# Issues while trying to run python through Anaconda3 from Git Bash

Tags: git, python3, git-bash

Please can someone help me understand (and resolve) whats going on.
I think my problem relates to some kind of path issue or permission issue, But I need help or direction/coaching to resolve this.
I am operating on a windows 10 machine. I am currently enrolled in a data science course and am trying to learn (so please bear with my ignorance).
I need to install Git Bash and Anaconda3 as I will be programming in Python and jupyter notebooks. (I have no problem in dowloading and installing the software).
However when I try to run python from git - bash, I have a bash: python: command not found error message. As per my attached screen shot - you can see the path where Ive installed Anaconda3. after "fiddling" around abit with putting anaconda in different paths I now get a /c/Users/Sondela/Anaconda3/python: Is a directory (see screen shot)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTcEq.png)

Answer (score 0):

This Issue is quite simple. You have been fiddling around with the `$PATH` Environment Variable, but not long enough.

The Error Message is quite self-descriptive. `/c/Users/Sondela/Anaconda3/python` is indeed a Folder and not an Executable Binary File.

You must have added just the `/c/Users/Sondela/Anaconda3/` Folder to your `$PATH` Environment Variable. When you type your `~/Anaconda3/python` Command-Line, you are instructing Bash to attempt to execute a Folder.

You should have added the Correct Path toward the `python` Executable Binary File to the `$PATH` Environment Variable. That could be the `/c/Users/Sondela/Anaconda3/python/bin` Folder or something similar. First check the Correct Location where the `python` Executable Binary File resides.

Comment: Thank you. Yes It makes sense now - and it works

Comment: I am glad that you have nailed it, @user7104840. I was afraid that I was not clear enough. These days I am having trouble making myself clear to people.